# How to hide element after two item in Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have a Array. I want to hide elements after two item and join +rest items length.

like this,

```
let array = ['farmer', 'boomer', 'singer', 'worker', 'doctor']
```

in html, look like this = farmer, boomer+3

```
methods: {
  sectorSelected(val){
    val.slice(0, 2).join("+" + val.length)
  }
}
```

i cant imagine right now and i really dont understand. thanks for help

Comment: I don’t think you want to use join like that, as that will put the provided value in between every value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not far off, but

- the join string should be `", "`
- you should concatenate on the result of `join`
- you want to subtract the two you're showing from `length`
- you want to `return` the result

So:

```
return val.slice(0, 2).join(", ") + "+" + (val.length - 2);
```

You might also need a check to make sure there are at least three entries in the array, something like:

```
return val.length < 3
    ? val.join(", ")
    : (val.slice(0, 2).join(", ") + "+" + (val.length - 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
methods: {
  sectorSelected(val){
    return val.slice(0, 2).join(", ") + "+" + (val.length - 2)
  }
}
```

Comment: That needs a `return`, and it needs parens (without them, the `- 2` at the end is applied to the string in front of it, converting the string to a number, and likely resulting in `NaN`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
let array = ['farmer', 'boomer', 'singer', 'worker', 'doctor'];

console.log(array.splice(0,2).join(", ") + "+" + array.length);
```

This can run for every possible test case like when array length is less than 3.